# In a C# web forms app using the Socket class, how can I send two consecutive messages?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am brand new to sockets.  A colleague supplied an application written in Python that has a TCP socket server running forever.  That program will be delivered to our customer, and will connect with a client application the customer will be providing.  I have written a little test WinFormas application in C# that should do what the customer's client app does.  I can send one message from the test program to the server, and the server responds correctly and sends an ack back.  I am now trying to send a second message, and I'm getting an exception: "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine".  Is there something I need to do to reset the client's socket before it can send another message?

The client's socket is originally set up in this loop:

```
    while (!connected)
    {
        try
        {
            if (m_sendSocket == null)
            {
                m_sendSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            }
            m_sendSocket.Connect(sendRemoteEP);
            connected = true;
            btnMoveItem.Enabled = true;
            btnCloseSockets.Enabled = true;
            btnOpenSockets.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch (SocketException socketEx)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to sockets: " + ex.Message);
            break;
        }
    }
```

The client is sending the messages in this method:

```
private void SendMessage(string message)
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    // Connect to a remote device.
    try {

        // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
        try 
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
            //    sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Encode the data string into a byte array.
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            // Send the data through the socket.
            int bytesSent = m_sendSocket.Send(msg);

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            int bytesRec = m_sendSocket.Receive(bytes);
            int ackDelay = 0;
            while (bytesRec == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                ackDelay += 500;
                if (ackDelay > 10000)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:/misc/mes_simulator.log", true))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("No transport information acknowledgement received in ten seconds.");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                bytesRec = m_sendSocket.Receive(bytes);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Acknowledgement message: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

            if (MessageBox.Show("Send duplicate message?", "Send another?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                // Send the data through the socket AGAIN to see if we can.
                bytesSent = m_sendSocket.Send(msg);

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                bytesRec = m_sendSocket.Receive(bytes);
                ackDelay = 0;
                while (bytesRec == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    ackDelay += 500;
                    if (ackDelay > 10000)
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:/misc/mes_simulator.log", true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("No transport information acknowledgement received in ten seconds.");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    bytesRec = m_sendSocket.Receive(bytes);
                }
            }

            //Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
            //    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));

            // Release the socket.
            // sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            // sender.Close();

        } 
        catch (ArgumentNullException ane) 
        {
            FormattedMessageBox.Show("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
        } 
        catch (SocketException se) 
        {
            FormattedMessageBox.Show("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            FormattedMessageBox.Show("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

After the answer was received saying it was probably something on the server side, I stripped down the server to the bare minimum.  The problem is still happening.  The server receives the first message and acknowledges it, but it never gets the second message.  Here's the server code:

```
import json
import threading

import socketserver
import time

with open('CAPS_TWMS_config.json', 'rt') as c:
    caps_config = json.load(c)

# We are listening on this port and all defined IP addresses
# listenPort = 5001
listenPort = caps_config["listen_port"]

# Were to send the information to.
clientIPAddress = '127.0.0.1'   # socket.gethostbyname('client')
# clientPort = 12345
clientPort = caps_config["send_port"]

dsnName = caps_config["dsn_name"]

# Message sequence number
sequence_num = 1
exit_app = False

class ListenSocketHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, this_server):
        socketserver.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, this_server)
        self.timeout = 10

    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = self.request.recv(1024).decode()
            print (str.format("dataString[21]: {0}; dataString[24:26]: {1}", data[21], data[24:26]))
            print ('ListenSocketHandler recv()-> "%s"' % data)
            print ('ListenSocketHandler recv().length-> "%d"' % len(data))

            if len(data) > 0:
                self.request.send("I got a message!".encode())
                return
        except Exception as value:
            print('ListenSocketHandler - %s' % str(value))

        return


class ListenServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    """
    The multi-threaded server that will spawn threads running the Socket Handler for each
    connection
    """
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        # Create the Server Handler for connections to this computer listening on all IP addresses,
        # change '' to 'x.x.x.x'  to listen on a specific IP network.  This class will listen for messages    # from CAPS.
        server = ListenServer(('', listenPort), ListenSocketHandler)
        ip, port = server.server_address

        # Start a thread with the server -- that thread will then start one
        # more thread for each request
        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
        server_thread.setDaemon(True)
        server_thread.start()

        while not exit_app:
            time.sleep(1)

        print ('Out of main loop.')
        server.shutdown()
        server.server_close()
    except Exception as value:
        print("Failed to do something: %s", str(value))
```

Comment: Use HWGroup Hercules as both, client and server, to test the other sides separately. Use Sysinternals TCPView to monitor your network connections. Both will help you to find out what your client and Server do

Comment: From what I can tell you are not doing any kind of [message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), that is the source of your problem I think. Pretend you are writing your messages to a file on the hard dive, closing your server, opening the client then reading the messages out of the file. How would the receiver know where one messaged stopped and another began?

Comment: The `while` loop in your client will never be entered, you can remove it. Reason: from MSDN: *If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available, unless a time-out value was set by using Socket.ReceiveTimeout.* this means, when `while ...` is reached, there has been data read because you haven't set a read timeout.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: no because after each send he is doing a receive, therefore each message will be transmitted separately. But anyway, a very helpful link for the OP!

Comment: @TobiasKnauss True that he will not get two messages in a single receive but he has no guard if he receives only half a message.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: that's a fair point. I doubt though that he will struggle with these issues here. However, you're right and he should implement that later.

Comment: He should implement it now.   What are all those Sleep() calls for?

Answer (score -1):

no , you dont need to do anything to be able to send several messages.

It smells like the server is disconnecting for some reason, but you didnt show that code

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer.  I added the server code to my original post.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this answer please explain your downvote?  I would very much like to know what I am doing wrong.